# How to determine [x,y,z] coordinate of PalmPosition for hand?

Tags: c#, leap-motion

```
HandList hands = frame.Hands;
Hand h = hands[0];
Vector pp = h.PalmPosition;
sw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:f4}, {0:f4}, {0:f4}", pp.x, pp.y, pp.z));
```

For this code, my output for x, y, and z are always the same. If I move in a circle around the loop, the x,y,z coordinates are always the same, which is not desirable.

How do I obtain the x,y,z coordinates for a Palm?

Comment: Maybe you are using the other hand lol, never used leap motion but try something like `frame = leap.frame();` above maybe that will update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be printing out `pp.x` 3 times, never using the other 2 variables, because the zero in `{0:f4}` specifies the first parameter after the format string itself -- `pp.x`.

```
string h = "Hello";
string w = "World!";

Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}, it is {2}.", h, w, DateTime.Now);
```

This silly example should make it more clear. Also notice that this overload of `Console.WriteLine` formats text just like `string.Format`.
More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).